# Scrapy extract only a portion of the url

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have the following spider:

```
start_urls = ['https://www.youtube.com/user/ZaidAliT/videos']

def parse_question(self, response):
    yield {
        'title': response.css('h1 span::text').extract()[0],
        'views': response.css('div .watch-view-count::text').extract()[0],
        'link': response.url,
    }
```

Currently when i parse, i get the entire links of the channel in the `response.url` like the following:

```
"link": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qEybDk00rJE"
```

How do i modify this such that i extract only the `qEybDk00rJE` part from the url?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
'link'=response.url.split('=')[-1]
```

This returns everything after the last '='

Answer (score 3):

I imagine you want the full query, if you want to parse a url, use urlparse:

```
In [1]: import urlparse

In [2]: url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qEybDk00rJE"

In [3]: parsed =  urlparse.urlparse(url)

In [4]: parsed
Out[4]: ParseResult(scheme='https', netloc='www.youtube.com', path='/watch', params='', query='v=qEybDk00rJE', fragment='')

In [5]: parsed.query
Out[5]: 'v=qEybDk00rJE'
```

If you do really only want what comes after the `=` you can then split the query.

.